# Does Ranma's dad prefer to be in Panda form?

Tags: ranma

After the first few episodes, for the rest of season 1, we see Ranma's father in his panda form almost exclusively.  For comparison, we see Ranma in both of his forms about equally.

Does Ranma's father prefer his Panda form?  Is this for comedic effect?  Or was it a budgetary thing (ie less voice acting)?

Comment: I don't remember anything specific was ever mentioned but he also seems to prefer his panda form in manga so probably it has nothing to do with voice acting